# Jquery Drag n Drop Stage

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am trying to create a stage.
I have 5 items in a draggable div. There clones will be dragged to 20 droppable areas.

I have created 20 boxes of divs with different ids. Means multiple drop able areas.

The problem is that I don't have the idea that how can I get id the of the div where the item is dropped and how, I will show that product only in that div. Right now it is displaying all of the items in a single first div.

The main problem is that how can we create multiple droppable areas dynamically and drop an item in that specific area.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You may wish to include some code with your question to clear up any questions about how you are implementing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**jQuery-UI Draggable Droppable event handler**

You need to get the droppable dom object from the event arguments passed to the drop method.

```
$( ".selector" ).droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) { 
    // $(this) represents the droppable.
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
  }
});
```

the draggable object can be referenced through `ui.draggable`. Most of this was taken from the jQuery-UI documentation found [at the jQuery-ui Website](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#event-drop)

**Adding Droppable to a Dynamically Added Element**

In the event that the elements, let's call them stage targets, are being added dynamically to the "stage" then you would want to call the `droppable` method on those elements when they are created.

```
function makeStageTargets(i) {
  for(i;i--;true){
    var d = $("div").attr("id","item_"+i); // this will make a div id item_i
    $("stage").append(d);
    d.droppable(
      drop:function(e, ui){
        var param = $(ui.draggable).attr('src');
        $("stage").remove(ui.draggable); // this will remove an item when dropped
        addlist(param);
      });
  }
}
makeStageTargets(60);
```

If I have missed the spirit of your question please advise.

Comment: Thanks Gabriel for your reply.
But the problem is, where comes the selector part in $( ".selector" ).
I have multiple multiple divs more than, 20 generated dynamically with ids like item_1, item_2 .. etc. Now at this point my item is dropped in, how I will be changing it dynamically.

Once again thanks for your help.

Comment: I think we are in the right direction, but there are total 5 items and they can be dropped multiple times, means clone of the item will be dropped there, and one thing more to restrict the user to drop a single item in droppable area.

Many thanks Gabriel. I was wondering around from many days, now I am getting some clue with your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I am using

$("div_item").droppable({

```
        drop:
            function(e, ui)
                {
                    var param = $(ui.draggable).attr('src');

                    addlist(param);
                }

});
```

Where addlist() is a function to get ajax contents and display in div like
$('#div_item').append(msg.txt);

'msg' variable to get the item detail from ajax file.

The problem is with id div_item. These are more than 20, colud be upto 60. I also want to restrict each div with a single dropped in it.
Many thanks for your help

Comment: generally the idea is to edit a question with the new relevant information. Answer posts should be kept for answers. I have updated my answer to answer what I believe your question to be. Though for clarity your question(s) are:

How do I add an element to the page dynamically?
How do I make that element droppable?
How do I make the items that are dropped onto it only droppable once?

I have attempted to address these questions in my answer.